# Installing Windows 8 from one partition to another?

Tags: installation, windows-8, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 8 on my HDD without the use of a USB or DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/490476/how-can-i-install-windows-8-on-my-hdd-without-the-use-of-a-usb-or-dvd)

Is it possible to install Windows 8 from one partition where i have the ISO to another partition just like an application.

The reason i am asking is because there i have no empty DVD's or a USB stick around and have no idea how to install it since holidays are here all shops are closed.

Any option to maybe emulate a partition as a USB mount Win 8 image on it and then boot it up on restart.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.
Run `Sources\Setup.exe` from the DVD image within Windows 7 and choose Custom Installation.

It will ask you which partition to install Windows 8 on; just select the second partition.
It will extract the Windows 8 files ono that partition, install the windows 8 boot loader, and reboot into Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having trouble because \Setup.exe assumes an in-place install.

Comment: oy, I can't tell you how much time I'd wasted before I found this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. During the install it will ask you which partition to install from.

[image: I will try to get a picture of the install to let you see what it looks like.]

Comment: Has nothing to do with my question. I asked if i can extract my ISO image on my Windows 7 partition and install windows 8 on a empty partition.

Also what you linked is image showing you can choose partition where to install not where to install from.