# How to install Windows 8 on laptop with Windows 7 using Virtual CloneDrive?

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, virtual-drive

I downloaded a student version of Windows 8 Pro and currently have it as an ISO. It tells me that I have to put it in a dvd in order to be able to install it, but I don't have access to one. Would I be able to install and run Windows 8 using Virtual Clone Drive? Also, by doing this, would I be able to keep the files, apps and services like Windows 8 promises to do?

Keep in mind that I'm extremely un-techy and unfamiliar with computer programming and the like.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to preserve your apps and whatnot, make sure you _don't_ follow the WAIK method of installing and just mount it in Virtual Clone Drive. Also make sure you're _upgrading_ and not installing fresh. I'm not sure if a different ISO file is provided for an upgrade.

Comment: This is the answer you want: http://superuser.com/a/491212/146694

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do this, you can install windows from USB drives.

That question has been asked and answered:

[Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)

Even though this Q&A is for Win7, the process is the same.

Comment: You will lose all your data if you do it this way.

Comment: yeah, but good decisions don't make good stories...

Comment: I am all for clean installs, just thought the user should know.

Comment: The easy transfer tool can back up all his files.