# Installing windows 8 over c drive(removing xp)

Tags: windows, installation, imagex

I tried to install windows 8 from an iso mounted at g drive but my old windows XP install is on c drive - the first partition  .
I intend to replace the os xp.
where should i place the imagex.exe? I can't place it on c drive as it would get erased at format.
so on boot i open cmd ...
c:/>
but how can i use imagex and iso for install which is at g drive
please help

Comment: Have you tried just running the installer in xp? [this](http://superuser.com/a/491212/10165) seems to indicate it may work, and I'd think it would fail gracefully if it didn't

Comment: @Ashlin - Use the Windows 8 upgrade Assistant it will do everything you need to do, allowing you to install Windows 8, without a media.  You don't need to format your partition to upgrade your Windows XP installation to Windows 8.

Comment: I think you're terribly confused, you can't just mount an ISO and install from there. You'll need to use the Microsoft tool to load the iso to a USB Flash Drive and boot to that.

Answer (score 1):

Better you get a pendrive. use the following tool to make the pendrive bootable using the iso image

```
http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html
```

It is microsoft's official tool to make windows 7 iso bootable on USB. But it can be also used to boot windows 8 bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft deployment toolkit to create the bootable media for you. Don't be messing with ImageX by hand unless you have to. The deployment share can be run from the USB if you like as well.