# Install Windows 8 inside Windows 7 when partition limit is reached

Tags: windows-8

I want to install Windows 8 on my Windows 7 machine which already has Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

The problem is I can't make a new partition because there is a limit of 4 partitions at the most which I can't cross.

Is there any thing like Wubi for Windows so that I can install Windows 8 inside Windows 7 as I could do for Ubuntu? I do not want to shift to Windows 8 without trying it out properly. Also please don't suggest the obvious option of using virtual machines, as it tends to slow down my system.

Comment: Try deleting your "default" SYSTEM partition to create a new one in its place (that is if you have a SYSTEM partition)

Comment: I've done a writeup of the whole procedure here http://superuser.com/questions/490233/how-would-i-do-a-vhd-install-of-windows-8-from-windows-7 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Windows 8 to a VHD file in an existing partition.
Scott Hanselman has a [detailed guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).  (the guide is for the Consumer Preview, but the same steps apply to the RTM)

The basic steps are:

1. Create a VHD file from Disk Management in Windows 7.
2. Boot to the Windows 8 installer
3. When it asks you to select a partition, press Shift+F10 to open a console.
4. Run diskpart, then type

   ```
   select vdisk file=C:\...
   attacher vdisk
   ```
5. Go back to the installer and click Refresh
6. Select the new disk
7. Complete the installation
8. ???
9. Profit!!!

You can also do this without a bootable installer using ImageX from the Windows AIK; see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx).

Comment: This is awesome! I never even thought of doing this.

Comment: Does this work with both the regular and Pro edition? In Windows 7 this is limited to Enterprise and Ultimate editions, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make one of the partitions as an extended partition. Then you can add more than 4 partitions. Use EaseUS Partition Manager or Partition Wizard